# Devices with Android + MIUI and setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to create custom selection menu but it does not work on a device with rom MIUI and Android 6. The result is common menu with `copy` and `select all` items. On other devices and simulators under clean Android it works just fine.

The code:

```
        textViewTop.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new android.view.ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateActionMode");

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPrepareActionMode");
            menu.clear();

            int quote_quick = R.drawable.ic_desktop_mac_black_24dp;
            int quote_add = R.drawable.ic_computer_black_24dp;
            int copy = R.drawable.ic_devices_other_black_24dp;

            menu.add(Menu.NONE, QUOTE_START, 3, "").setIcon(quote_quick).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, QUOTE_ADD, 2, "").setIcon(quote_add).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, CUSTOM_COPY, 1, "").setIcon(copy).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: this is *apparently* a bug in [/system/framework/framework.jar](http://en.miui.com/thread-233931-1-1.html) See also [MIUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI). Your question is remarkably similar to [this](http://julene-lharudhar.blogspot.com/2011/02/textview-devices-with-android-miui-and.html) *unanswered* question on a *blogspot* from February 2011, how strange. The version of your **MIUI** might be helpful (**must be** >= **V7**)

Comment: I don't have MIUI device to test. Did you tried returning `true` in `onPrepareActionMode` method?

Comment: Haven't found any workaround so far. My only observation is that a similar functionality works in a WebView on a Xiaomi device. Let me know if it interests you I can provide example code.

Comment: Thank everyone for a reply! Now I have my test device Redmi 4A updated to Android 7.1.2 and MIUI 9 Global 8.5.19 and the issue is still here.

Comment: hey @micdev did you find any solution?

Comment: @Deepak Vajpayee No solution yet. I wonder that not so much complains for the subject.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a workaround, but it makes sense only if you absolutely need it to work on MIUI devices. It's generally a little awkward:

I noticed that the Wikipedia app has custom actions working on a Xiaomi device, and after looking through the code I found out it works fine when the texts is selected in a `WebView`.
You can basically use a `WebView` and override `onActionModeStarted` in your **Activity**

Acivity:

```
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head>\n" +
        "</head>\n" +
        "<body>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<h1>WebView text</h1>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>\n";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}

@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        menu.clear();
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_text_select, menu);
}
```

Menu:

```
<item android:id="@+id/id1"
      android:title="miui"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/id2"
      android:title="has"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/id3"
      android:title="bugs"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/id4"
    android:title="D:"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: I need solution for TextView, changing TextView to WebView seems like too much work for me as lots has already been done in my app using TextView

Comment: Then muiu has to be fixed

Comment: Is there another way without Webview now?

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts. What if you take menu item `onCreateOptionsMenu` and change it.

**Like this:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
  getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  new Handler().post( -> {
      final View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu_action_item);
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not help. I need more detailed information with code sample

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#CAB you need to create menu in onCreateActionMode.

I made it like this (in kotlin):

```
    val actionModeCallbackA = object : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, p1: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onActionItemClicked")
        actionModeB = startActionMode(actionModeCallbackB)
        return true
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onCreateActionMode")
        val inflater = mode?.getMenuInflater()
        inflater?.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(p0: ActionMode?, p1: Menu?): Boolean {
        Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onPrepareActionMode")
        return false
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(p0: ActionMode?) {
        Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onDestroyActionMode")
            actionModeA = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, maybe my solution would help someone. I had to make a view composed of several horizontal neighboring `EditText`'s, and add ability to paste text to them  (one letter of text to one editText)
I used `ActionMode.Callback`'s approach and it was working fine, except Xiaomi devices. The solution for Xiaomi devices was using `OnLongClickListener` on edit texts and create `PopupMenu` on long click:

```
editText.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(context,v);
    MenuInflater inflater = menu.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.paste_menu_item, menu.getMenu());
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
       pasteText();//some custom function to handle selected action
       return false;
    });
    menu.show();
    return true;
});
```