# Android TextView empty area long-touch context menu for TextView, not text selection menu

Tags: android, textview, android-widget

It seems that on a `TextView`, on which text selection is enabled, if I long-touch an empty area, the nearest word gets selected and the text selection context menu is shown. Is it possible to change this, and show a different context menu for the `TextView` itself, without selecting the nearest word?

What I mean is: long-touching on a word shows the context menu for the selected word (things like "copy/cut/select all"), and long-touching on an empty area shows the context menu for the `TextView` (something like "reload the page").

---

PS: People did not seem to understand "empty space". The area marked with a yellow line is what I meant.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FF0000"
                    android:text="@string/large_text"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "an empty area", can you please provide some explanations or a picture? It's an area between words, between lines or around the text?

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for, you can do it with `TextView` + `View`, make `TextView` width **wrap_content**, so if the user long-clicking on the empty area (View in this case) show your menu

Comment: I simply meant the visually empty area that we see. I can be technically between words or an empty line between two paragraphs, but the space between "material metaphor" and "is the", at the top of the screenshot I added, are visually different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `TextView` + `View`, here's an example :

**XML :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/emptyArea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java :**

```
 findViewById(R.id.emptyArea).setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On emptyArea clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        });
```

Or you can use the `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()`

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });
```

Be aware, for some reason, the `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` is [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165150/devices-with-android-miui-and-setcustomselectionactionmodecallback) with MIUI (Xiaomi devices).